# CSS make free space decrease first when window is shrinked

Tags: html, css, window

I have just started HTML/CSS this week, so sorry if I sound stupid anywhere. Anyway, here's my question:

I am programming a website where all the content is enclosed by a border. The margins to the left and right are 25%. Now, when I shrink the browser, all of the content stays 25% inside the browser always. I want the site to first use up the 25% free space on the left and right... If I'm not explaining properly, I'll show an example. When you are reading a PDF file(http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf open to try) and you shrink the window size, the A4 page sized block (all the content) does not shrink until all the grey space on the left and right has been used up. I want to have that in my website. Here are screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBTU0.png  <-- full size 
SKkt4DK.png  <-- shirnkied window

Cant post more than 2 links, that's why i only put the image ID. So yeah, how can I achieve this?

Edit: I've tried the positioning properties before but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is have your inner content sit in a container. The container's width should be 100% of the page, and your inner content's left/right margins set to auto.

That way when the page's width shrinks, the container still takes 100% of the width, but the inner content's margins are adjusting to the new changes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #container{
        width:100%;
        height:800px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    #content{
        width:800px;
        height:100%;
        background-color: green;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

**Demo :**
http://jsfiddle.net/zvo4u72x/

Adjust accordingly, but using this sample code should demonstrate what you need.